# Socket IO Multiple Node with Cluster Redis Adapter, is possible?

Tags: redis, socket.io, load-balancing

Yesterday, i try to make realtime app with socket io with multiple node, in reference using redis adapter, redis adapter define ip address and port,

in multiple node, app separate with nginx loadbalance, one redis adapter.. it is running well..

my question is, if hundred client hit app, and app hit one redis adapter, i think this can make server slowly.. can implement loadbalance/cluster in redis adapter too ???

i try to find this answer, i found using ioredis, but im not sure...